# Курсор на границе окна

Tags: winapi, c++

Добрый день. Встретил приложение, в котором при наведении курсора на границу окна - курсор не меняется (остается стрелочкой), но можно кликнуть и растянуть окно или уменьшить. Как это было сделано ? Поиск по существующим стилям окна внятного ответа не дал. Приложение написано на ATL, поэтому и окна стандартные - виндовые. Может быть кто-то может подсказать, какие стили были применены или какие дополнительные параметры ? Или в каком направлении копать ? Всем спасибо за участие и ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рамка окна приложения входит в неклиентскую область. Можно переопределить обработчики окна для неклиентской части окна и задать для них форму курсора. Либо взять и перебрать всевозможные комбинации [стилей](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx), включая [расширенные](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: WS_SIZEBOX не будет работать без WS_CAPTION